# jquery slider not working after wordpress update

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, slider

i have a wordpress website, the live link is [enter link description here](http://molugu.com/yantraev/)

there are two similar image slider sections after the main slider in the website, as both the slider sections was not set to autoplay by default i had to place the following code in footer:

```js
(function($){

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.swiper-container').attr('data-autoplay', 1);
     
  });

})(jQuery);
```

it was working fine until yesterday the wordpress version was updated, now both the image slider sections are not working, can anyone please tell me what could be the problem, thanks in advance

Comment: The browser's console is whole red from errors and yellow from warnings, fix the bugs first to check what else may be wrong. i.e. *missing jquery.min.js* Currently, your query is marked for closing because it needs debugging details.

Comment: ... and here are you can find instructions on how to access your browsers console (courtesy of monday.com): https://support.monday.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002197259-How-to-Open-the-Developer-Console

Comment: @biesior bro fixed most issues, can u please check now

Comment: Most != all, sometimes (most often) any single bug can avoid from proper page rendering, please fix all of them, then it will be possible to focus on the slider's issue. BTW it's quite possible that if you'll fix all bugs the slider will start to work again.